# pass data from a service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins

i have a factory am passing it to controller `LoginCtrl`

```
.factory('Fbdata', function(){
    var service = {
        data: {
          apiData: []
        },
        login: function () {
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"],
              function() {
            facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,email,name,picture", ["public_info","user_birthday"],
                function (results) {
                    service.data.apiData = results;
                    console.log(service.data.apiData);
                    return results;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error('FB:API', error);
                });
              },
               function(err) {
                console.error('FB:Login', err);
            });
        }
    };
    return service;
})
```

LoginCtrl:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Fbdata){
    $scope.login = function(){
        if (!window.cordova) {
            var appId = "appId";
            facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
        }

        $scope.loginData = Fbdata.login();
        console.log(Fbdata.data.apiData);
        // got empty array []
        $scope.retVal= angular.copy(Fbdata.data.apiData);
    };
})
```

the `Fbdata.data.apiData` return empty array and i only could see the returned data from the login success function in the console .
my template which is has `LoginCtrl` as controller:

```
  <div class="event listening button" ng-click="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
    <h2>{{loginData.name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{retVal.name}}</h2>
```

Comment: loginData Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}

apiData Object {id: "10201709610902307", email: "emai@exaple.com", name: "name", picture: Object}

here is the log and it works. I also can show the data inside the template. In addition you were right about chaining the functions you can call them independently using a promise .
I would like to thank you a lot for solve my problem and teach me a lot.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out for you. BTW, you probably know this already, but since `login()` responds with a `authResponse.status` of 'connected' I would put in an if statement in the first/success callback function that if it's not 'connected' then reject otherwise accept. Hope I made sense. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variety of ways to achieve this, example:

Now I have never used [`Cordova Facebook Plugin`](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) so I'm not sure if you need to run the api function after the log in, or how those procedures need to be ordered. But I wanted to show you an example of how to retrieve the data from the `factory` using your code sample. Hope that helps

---

**Edit 2**:

I have changed my code to using promises that way we make sure that we don't call one without the other being completed, I am not a fan of chaining the `login` and `api` functions within one function since it is possible(?) that you may need to call `login()` but don't want to call `api()`, please try my code and paste in your console logs in the bottom of your question.

**Factory:**

```
// Let's add promises to our factory using AngularJS $q
.factory('Fbdata', ['$q', function($q){
    // You could also just replace `var service =` with `return` but I thought this
    // would make it easier to understand whats going on here.
    var service = {
        // I generally nest result to keep it clean when I log
        // So results from functions that retrieve results are stored here
        data: {
            login: [],
            api: []
        },
        api: function() {
            var q = $q.defer();
            facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,email,name,picture", ["public_info","user_birthday"],
                function (results) {
                    // assign to the object being returned
                    service.data.api = results;
                    // The data has returned successfully so we will resolve our promise
                    q.resolve(results);
                },
                function (error) {
                    // We reject here so we can inform the user within through the error/reject callback
                    q.reject(error);
                    console.error('FB:API', error);
                });
            // Now that we have either resolved or rejected based on what we received
            // we will return the promise
            return q.promise;
        },
        login: function () {
            var q = $q.defer();
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], function (results) {
                // assign to the object being returned
                service.data.login = results;
                q.resolve(results);
            }, function(err) {
                q.reject(error);
                console.error('FB:Login', err);
            });
            return q.promise;
        }
    };
    return service;
}])
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Fbdata){
    $scope.login = function(){
        if (!window.cordova) {
            var appId = "appid";
            facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
        }
        // By using the promises in our factory be can ensure that API is called after
        // login by doing the following

        // then(success, reject) function allows us to say once we have a return, do this.
        Fbdata.login().then(function () {
            $scope.loginData = Fbdata.data.login;
            // Check what was returned
            console.log('loginData', $scope.loginData);
            Fbdata.api().then(function () {
                $scope.apiData = Fbdata.data.api;
                console.log('apiData', $scope.apiData);
            }, function () {
                // Tell the user that the api failed, if necessary
            });
        }, function () {
            // Tell the user that the log in failed
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you it work and i learned a lot from your great answer.

Comment: hello Asok, i got another problem here since i got to know **Cordova Facebook Plugin **need to call login before calling the api so i altered the previous code and called the api in the success of the login 

But i got another issue which is apiData: [] where i put the returned data (id,name, and pic) is empty when i call it in the controller, i edited my question to match my new code.

Comment: I will edit my answer to be a possible resolution here in a second